# Find the intersection curve between a plane $x+y=1$ and a sphere $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given two equations:

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1\\ 
x+y=1
\end{matrix}\right.$

Find the set of points in $3$-space represented by this pair.

My work so far:

The equation $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1$ represents a sphere with radius $1$ centered at the origin. The equation $x+y=1$ represents a plane in the $xy$-plane that has the points (1, 0, 0) and (0, 1, 0).

I am not sure how to find the equation of the curve (the circle) that is formed from the intersection of these two equations. Do I use substitution?

Let $x = 1 - y$.

$(1-y)^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1$

$1-2y+y^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1$

$2\left (y-\frac{1}{2}  \right )^{2}+z^{2}=\frac{1}{2}$

I am close to the answer in the textbook, which is a circle with radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ centered at (1/2, 1/2, 0).

I know that the circle is in the $xy$-plane, so $z = 0$. However, how did they get the $x = \frac{1}{2}$ coordinate when I don't see $x$ in the equation...?

Comment: The circle is not in the xy-plane. It is in the plane where $x+y=1$.

Comment: $x+y=1$ does not mean that $z=0$ it's a plane that contains z axis

Comment: There are several solutions to this and similar problems in the related questions at right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivation is correct but from here

$$2\left (y-\frac{1}{2}  \right )^{2}+z^{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$y = 1 - x$$

you find

$$\left (1-x-\frac{1}{2}  \right )^{2}+\left (y-\frac{1}{2}  \right )^{2}+z^{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\left (x-\frac{1}{2}  \right )^{2}+\left (y-\frac{1}{2}  \right )^{2}+z^{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

which is the equation of a sphere centered in $C(\frac12,\frac12,0)$ and with radius $R=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$.

Since the center belongs to the plane $x+y=1$ then the intersection between the sphere and the plane is a circle with center $C(\frac12,\frac12,0)$ and radius $R=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$.

Comment: Oh, because the coefficient is 2, so algebraically this works! I totally get it now from your answer. I was also thinking about substituting y = 1 - x but I didn't know how until you showed me.

Comment: Yes by this geometric interpretation it’s immediately clear. Well done, Bye!

Answer (score 1):

You know from geometry that the intersection is a circle, but the writing the equation of a circle in 3D isn't so straightforward (different forms can exist).

To ease the task, we can rotate space in such a way that the plane becomes parallel to $yz$. We will use the transform

$$x,y,z\to\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2},\frac{x-y}{\sqrt2},z.$$

The equation of the plane becomes

$$x=\frac1{\sqrt2}$$ and that of the sphere

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1,$$ which is no surprise as the sphere is symmetrical.

Now the circle has the 2D equation

$$y^2+z^2=\frac12.$$

It has the radius $\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$ and the center $\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt2},0,0\right)$ in the rotated coordinates. We counter-rotate with

$$x,y,z\to\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2},\frac{x-y}{\sqrt2},z$$

and the center moves to

$$\left(\frac12,\frac12,0\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

Points of intersection will satisfy both equations, thus $x^2+y^2+z^2=x+y=1$. Simplifying $x^2+y^2+z^2=x+y$ we get $x^2-x+y^2-y+z^2=0$ or $(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+(y-\frac{1}{2})^2+z^2=\frac{1}{2}$. Don't be alarmed that it looks like another sphere, there is no general equation for a circle in 3d, we can only write it on a particular plane, which is $x+y=1$ in this case.